# Folder on Android device where crash information is kept

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have a virtual space on Android device which is cleaned up every app launch, and I need to manually specify which folders to copy and paste to a next session. Which folder should I keep between sessions in order to make app crashes information passed to Crashlytics?

Comment: Crashlytics tracks app crashes on its own as far as I know, if this is not the expected answer then please add some code so that it will be clear what you exactly intend to do

Comment: @gtxtreme I know that Crashlytics tracks crashes on it's own and the question is about where it keeps it's cache files. There was an assumption that he saves them locally because within my virtual environment (where each app session starts from scratch for file system except folders which I point out) I do not receive crashes info within Crashlytics. While the same build within usual Android environment works ok (I see crashes in admin panel), so I'm sure it's settled up correctly. The question doesn't involve any code.